# subprocess.check_output of service state on Remote

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, systemctl, sshpass

I want to check the status of `<SERVICE>` on [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) instance (standard connection is `ssh root@192.168.7.2`).

When I do

```
sshpass -p none ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.7.2 -t 'systemctl is-active <SERVICE>'
```

I got expected output:

```
failed
```

If I try to use `subprocess.check_output` for the same as

```
subprocess.check_output("sshpass -p none ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.7.2 -t 'systemctl is-active <SERVICE>'", shell=True, encoding='utf8', stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

I got

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in 
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
> return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True, File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run raise
> CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'sshpass -p none ssh -o
> StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.7.2 -t 'systemctl is-active
> <SERVICE>'' returned non-zero exit status 3.

But if I use the same code-line with any other command, e.g.

```
 subprocess.check_output("sshpass -p none ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.7.2 -t 'echo $PATH'", shell=True, encoding='utf8', stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

I got expected output:

```
'/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin\n'
```

So why `subprocess.check_output` doesn't work correctly with `systemctl`?

Answer (score 0):

I got the service status by replacing `check_output` method with `run` as

```
subprocess.run("sshpass -p none ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.7.2 -t 'systemctl is-active <SERVICE>'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stdout
```

but that looks more like a workaround since `check_output` should be used specifically for getting the command output and `run` is general method to execute commands...

**Update**

Also `getstatusoutput` works as

```
subprocess.getstatusoutput("sshpass -p none ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.7.2 -t 'systemctl is-active <SERVICE>'")
```

However, it returns exitcode along with the status

```
(3, 'failed\nConnection to 192.168.7.2 closed.')
```

so required output should be parsed additionaly

Answer (score 0):

`check_output` checks that the command succeeds; if the service is not running, the command fails. So running without the `check` is precisely what you want here.

For the record, `subprocess.check_output(cmd)` is basically equivalent to `subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, text=True, capture_output=True).stdout`

You want to avoid the `shell=True`; see [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

```
result = subprocess.run(
    ["sshpass", "-p", "none",
     "ssh", "-o", "StrictHostKeyChecking=no",
     "root@192.168.7.2", "-t",
     f"systemctl is-active {SERVICE}"],
     capture_output=True, text=True, encoding='utf8',
     stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL).stdout
```